# Android: Kotlin execution failed while trying to use Databinding

Tags: android, data-binding, kotlin

I am trying to bind views using the **new android Databinding Library**. I tried running the app and got the following error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
>   Internal compiler error. See log for more details

Below is my **MainActivity.kt**:

```
import android.databinding.DataBindingUtil
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import app.android.androidtexteditor.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import app.android.androidtexteditor.models.TextEditor


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)

    var textEditor = TextEditor("content")
    binding.textEditor = textEditor
    binding.executePendingBindings()

 }
}
```

Below is my **TextEditor.kt**:

```
class TextEditor(var content: String?)
```

Below is my **activity_main.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    >

    <data>
        <variable
            name="textEditor"
            type="app.android.androidtexteditor.models.TextEditor"/>
    </data>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        >
            <jp.wasabeef.richeditor.RichEditor
                android:id="@+id/text_editor_content"
                android:text="@{textEditor.content}"
                android:layout_width="327dp"
                android:layout_height="478dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:padding="20dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

NOTE: The app complies fine when `android:text="@{textEditor.content}"` is removed from XML.

**EDIT:**

Below are the logs:

> 2017-11-11 14:13:24,608 [thread 118]   INFO -
>   s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from
>   /private/var/folders/tw/_9p_vd716zz1mr4lkp_69h880000gn/T/AppTranslocation/3BF8BBE1-C94A-4F85-9008-1FC1B3EE13FB/d/Android
>   Studio 3.1 Preview.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home  2017-11-11
>   14:13:24,683 [thread 118]   INFO - oject.common.GradleInitScripts -
>   init script file sync.local.repo contents "allprojects {\n 
>   buildscript {\n    repositories {\n      maven { url
>   '/private/var/folders/tw/_9p_vd716zz1mr4lkp_69h880000gn/T/AppTranslocation/3BF8BBE1-C94A-4F85-9008-1FC1B3EE13FB/d/Android
>   Studio 3.1 Preview.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository'}\n    }\n  }\n 
>   repositories {\n      maven { url
>   '/private/var/folders/tw/_9p_vd716zz1mr4lkp_69h880000gn/T/AppTranslocation/3BF8BBE1-C94A-4F85-9008-1FC1B3EE13FB/d/Android
>   Studio 3.1 Preview.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository'}\n  }\n}\n" 
>   2017-11-11 14:13:24,684 [thread 118]   INFO -
>   ild.invoker.GradleBuildInvoker - Build command line options:
>   [--configure-on-demand, -Pandroid.injected.invoked.from.ide=true,
>   --init-script, /private/var/folders/tw/_9p_vd716zz1mr4lkp_69h880000gn/T/sync.local.repo2551.gradle]
>   2017-11-11 1
>
> 4:13:24,684 [thread 118]   INFO - xecution.GradleExecutionHelper -
>   Passing command-line args to Gradle Tooling API: --configure-on-demand
>   -Pandroid.injected.invoked.from.ide=true --init-script /private/var/folders/tw/_9p_vd716zz1mr4lkp_69h880000gn/T/sync.local.repo2551.gradle
>   2017-11-11 14:13:24,921 [thread 100]   INFO -
>   idea.project.IndexingSuspender - Indexing suspended (context: Gradle
>   Build)  2017-11-11 14:13:26,683 [thread 100]   INFO -
>   idea.project.IndexingSuspender - Indexing released (context: Gradle
>   Build)  2017-11-11 14:13:26,686 [thread 116]   INFO -
>   roid.sdk.MessageBuildingSdkLog -
>   com.android.ide.common.blame.Message.(com.android.ide.common.blame.Message$Kind,
>   java.lang.String, java.lang.String,
>   com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList) 
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
>   com.android.ide.common.blame.Message.(com.android.ide.common.blame.Message$Kind,
>   java.lang.String, java.lang.String,
>   com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList)  at
>   java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)  at j
>
> ava.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1825)    at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.KotlinOutputParserHelper$simpleMessageConstructor$2.invoke(KotlinOutputParserHelper.kt:171)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.KotlinOutputParserHelper$simpleMessageConstructor$2.invoke(KotlinOutputParserHelper.kt:143)
>     at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(Lazy.kt:130)    at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.KotlinOutputParserHelper.getSimpleMessageConstructor(KotlinOutputParserHelper.kt)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.KotlinOutputParserHelper.createNewMessage(KotlinOutputParserHelper.kt:272)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.KotlinOutputParserHelper.createMessage(KotlinOutputParserHelper.kt:250)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.KotlinOutputParserHelper.createMessage$default(KotlinOutputParserHelper.kt:244)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.KotlinOutputParserHelperKt.parse(KotlinOutputParserHelper.kt:41)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.KotlinOutputParser.parse(KotlinOutputParser.java:28)
>     at
>   com.android.ide.common.blame.parser.ToolOutputParser.parseToolOutput(ToolOutputParser.java:86)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.gradle.output.parser.BuildOutputParser.parseGradleOutput(BuildOutputParser.java:43)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.build.invoker.GradleTasksExecutorImpl.lambda$collectMessages$5(GradleTasksExecutorImpl.java:487)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$2.run(ApplicationImpl.java:334)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 2017-11-11 14:13:26,687
>   [thread 116]   INFO - roid.sdk.MessageBuildingSdkLog - Exception from
>   KotlinOutputParser  2017-11-11 14:13:26,817 [e-1012-b01]   INFO -
>   ild.invoker.GradleBuildInvoker - Gradle build finished with 1 error(s)
>   in 2s 79ms  2017-11-11 14:13:26,868 [e-1012-b01]   INFO -
>   pl.ProjectRootManagerComponent - project roots have changed 
>   2017-11-11 14:13:27,145 [thread 119]   INFO -
>   .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Pushing properties took 1ms; general
>   responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok  2017-11-11 14:13:27,184
>   [thread 119]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Indexable file
>   iteration took 38ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness:
>   ok  2017-11-11 14:13:28,217 [J pool 1/4]   WARN -
>   hes.resolve.KotlinCacheService - Could not find correct module
>   information. Reason: Analyzing element of type class
>   com.android.tools.idea.databinding.LightGeneratedComponentClass with
>   no containing file Text: null  2017-11-11 14:13:28,217 [J pool 1/4]
>   WARN - .resolve.jvm.JvmAnalyzerFacade - Java referenced null from
>   LibraryInfo(libraryName=com.android.databinding:library-1.3.1)
>   Referenced class was: JavaClassImpl: DATA binding component class
>   2017-11-11 14:13:28,217 [J pool 1/4]   WARN -
>   hes.resolve.KotlinCacheService - Could not find correct module
>   information. Reason: Analyzing element of type class
>   com.android.tools.idea.databinding.LightGeneratedComponentClass with
>   no containing file Text: null  2017-11-11 14:13:28,217 [J pool 1/4]
>   WARN - .resolve.jvm.JvmAnalyzerFacade - Java referenced null from
>   LibraryInfo(libraryName=com.android.databinding:library-1.3.1)
>   Referenced class was: JavaClassImpl: DATA binding component class

Comment: does it compile if you remove `android:text="@{textEditor.content}"`?

Comment: Yea it compiles when I remove it

Comment: ok, so whats in the logs? (`"Internal compiler error. See log for more details"`)

Comment: Opened Logcat but there is nothing specific to the error

Comment: where else do i view logs?

Comment: `logcat` shows your device/emulator logs - in your case your app does not compile, so it is not even launched - you need to open android studio logs

Comment: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.android.ide.common.blame.Message.<init>(com.android.ide.common.blame.Message$Kind, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList)`

Comment: Also added the logs the question. Please check it out, it would be great if you could help me out with this

Answer (score 0):

After hours of researching, I found out that the third party library I was using is the issue: `RichEditor`. It didn't support `android: text`.